# Order a correlogram

Tags: r, correlation, clustering, similarities

I have 30 days data, and I am plotting correlogram using [corrplot](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/visualize-correlation-matrix-using-correlogram) (R package). I have an option to order the correlogram with [hclust](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/visualize-correlation-matrix-using-correlogram) option and hence I obtain plot as shown on right side of below figure
[image]

I want to know how `hclust` option is working? Does it first computes the sum of each row/column of correlation matrix and then arranges the correlogram according to the decreasing order of sum found or there is some other logic to order the correlogram in this order?

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchical Clustering is a clustering algorithm, that can also be used to order elements. Essentially, it will order them such that very similar items are very close.

See the documentation of the [`hclust`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/hclust.html) function:

> Hierarchical cluster analysis on a set of dissimilarities and
>        methods for analyzing it.